# Crawling output into multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I would like to know how to export my results from crawling into multiple csv files for each different city that I have crawled. Somehow I´m running into walls, do not get a proper way to sort it out.

That is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357.124'}
output_file= open("TA.csv", "w", newline='')
RegionIDArray = [187147,187323,186338]
dict = {187147: 'Paris', 187323: 'Berlin', 186338: 'London'}
already_printed = set()

for reg in RegionIDArray:
    for page in range(1,700,30):
        r = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attractions-c47-g" + str(reg) + "-oa" + str(page) + ".html")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

        g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "element_wrap"})

        for item in g_data:
            header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "property_title"})
            item = (header[0].text.strip())
            if item not in already_printed:
                already_printed.add(item)

                print("POI: " + str(item) + " | " + "Location: " + str(dict[reg]))

                writer = csv.writer(output_file)
                csv_fields = ['POI', 'Locaton']
                if g_data:
                    writer.writerow([str(item), str(dict[reg])])
```

My goal would be that I get three sperate CSV files for Paris, Berlin and London instead of getting all the results in one big csv file.

Could you guys help me out? Thanks for your feedback:)

Comment: You might want to look into the TripAdvisor Content API instead: https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I´m quite aware of that but I would like to crawl it on my own. Somehow, its motivating than rather using the API;)

Comment: If you want to write to three different files based on content, you have to have three separate ```csv.writer```'s, test the content and write to the correct file, depending on the test results.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. But still I dont know how to seperate the cities into three different csv files. I get your point to have three seperate csv writers but how should I split it

Comment: Don't use dict as a name of anything.  You shadow the builtin type dict.  Rename it to RegionIDArray, since you don't need that.  Iterating over the dict will give you the keys anyway in your 'for reg in Region..."

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Sorry, I´m just new to Python and crawling and dont get it fully what you stated above. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: You shouldn't ever use a name that is used by python.  dict is such a name.

Comment: It's certainly a good experience to write your own crawler, but FYI doing this is against TripAdvisor's [terms of use](https://www.tripadvisor.com/pages/terms.html), unless of course you've arranged it with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some minor modifications to your code.  To make files for each locale, I moved the out_file name inside the loop.

Note, that I don't have time now, the very last line is a hack to ignore unicode errors -- it just skips trying to output a line with a non ascii character.  Thas isn't good.  Maybe someone can fix that part?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Chrome/43.0.2357.124'}
RegionIDArray = {187147: 'Paris', 187323: 'Berlin', 186338: 'London'}
already_printed = set()

for reg in RegionIDArray:
    output_file= open("TA" + str(reg) + ".csv", "w")
    for page in range(1,700,30):
        r = requests.get("https://www.tripadvisor.de/Attractions-c47-g" + str(reg) + "-oa" + str(page) + ".html")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

        g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "element_wrap"})

        for item in g_data:
            header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "property_title"})
            item = (header[0].text.strip())
            if item not in already_printed:
                already_printed.add(item)

                # print("POI: " + str(item) + " | " + "Location: " + str(RegionIDArray[reg]))

                writer = csv.writer(output_file)
                csv_fields = ['POI', 'Locaton']
                if g_data:
                    try:
                        writer.writerow([str(item), str(RegionIDArray[reg])])
                    except:
                        pass
```